# Failing to connect to Azure DB via SSH-Tunnel using a JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, ssh-tunnel

I am unable to connect to an Azure DB via SSH-Tunnel using a JDBC connection.
For security reasons, I cannot directly access the Azure DB, but I have a jump server / tunnel VM that I can use to indirectly connect to the DB.

- command line access (via JDBC) to the Azure DB works from the tunnel VM
- establishing an SSH tunnel (`ssh -f vm_user@tunnel_vm_host -L 127.0.0.1:1433:mydb-server.database.windows.net:1433 -N`) and then connecting to the Azure DB via `127.0.0.1:1433` and `dbuser@mydb-server.database.windows.net` works, if I use a client using the MS OLE DB SQL driver
- establishing a connection using the MS SQL JDBC driver fails: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.yyy.zzz.worker.database.windows.net, port 11111 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".`
- from what I can see with Wireshark, if the JDBC driver is used, the communication to the Azure DB is started using the tunnel (`127.0.0.1:randomport <--> 127.0.0.1:1433`), but then switches to outside the tunnel, using `my-external-IP:randomport <--> xxx.yyy.zzz.worker.database.windows.net:11111`, which fails due to the firewall.

What am I missing to get this running?

Drivers used:

- JDBC driver version is mssql 8.2.2.0 jre11
- MS OLE DB Driver for SQL Server 18.3.0.0

Test program:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class AzureDbTest {
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws SQLException {
    final String user = "db-user@mydb-server.database.windows.net";
    final String password = "password";
    final int portNumber = 1433;
    final String databaseName = "mydb";
    final String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
    final String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%s;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;",
        serverName, portNumber, databaseName, user, password);
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      final String schema = connection.getSchema();
      System.out.println("Successful connection - Schema: " + schema);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you you why the port changed to '11111' when MS SQL JDBC driver used?

Comment: I did not change the port. That is something done by the driver (I think). the changed host and port are reported by the exception and I can see, that the test program switches the connection from 127.0.0.1:1433 to the host and port reported in the exception. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **connection policy** of the DB server needs to be **proxy** in order to work with the ssh tunnel.

Details on the differences of the available connection policies can be found in the [Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics connectivity architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture) article.